# Different colors for same variable type in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

VSCode color codes variables differently, even though they are of the same type (as shown below). Is there a sensible reason for this? Does VSCode perhaps consider "links" a keyword? It happens with `.id` as well..

[image]

I am using the Boron theme and ES6 through webpack/babel.

Comment: Try [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) on the StackExchange network for problems related to specific hardware/software. StackOverflow is about programming only. While VSCode does do programming, your question seems to be about the VSCode application itself.

Comment: I cannot comment yet - sorry. I've created issue on VSCode github repository. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-TmLanguage/issues/657

Answer (score 0):

Every theme has Different colors. Download a theme from Extensions
then change the theme from,
**File> Preferences > Color Theme**

Comment: I know about color themes. As you see i use Boron, which is not a standard theme. I am asking about the logic behind this example, where two variables defined in the exact same way are somehow registered in two different ways and thus colored differently.. It’s not a question about colors per se but the way VSCode processes javascript